# Connection to a local Tomcat server through virtual interfaces

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, nat, gateway

I am hoping to connect to a Tomcat server on a local host from virtual machines running on VMWare Station that connects to the host with a NAT virtual network.

I started a Tomcat server with port 8080 on my host PC.

The host normally has the following interfaces:

> 1. Loopback interface, IP: 127.0.0.1
> 2. An interface for the ethernet, IP: 10.10.31.194   Gateway: 10.10.31.254
>    The IP and DNS values are automatically assigned.
> 3. A virtual interface for the virtual network VNet8, IP: 192.168.129.1  Gateway: 192.168.129.2
>    The IP and DNS values are automatically assigned. (This interface appears after the VMNet 8 is setup, to reduce confusion)

I can connect to a webpage (say /helloProject/helloPage.html) on the Tomcat server with the following URLs:

```
   http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloProject/helloPage.html

   http://10.10.31.194:8080/helloProject/helloPage.html
```

Then I setup my VMWare Station and opened a Network Address Translation network with the following configurations:

> VMNet8
>
> DHCP: Enabled
>
> Subnet Address: 192.168.129.0
>
> Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
>
> Gateway IP: 192.168.129.2

But I cannot connect to the helloPage.html webpage through:

```
http://192.168.129.1:8080/helloProject/helloPage.html
```

Either from the host itself with IP 192.168.129.1, or from a Linux CentOS virtual machine with IP 192.168.129.128 on the same network.

However, pinging the host from the host or the Linux VM I get response:

> ping 192.168.129.1
>
> Reply from 192.168.129.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
>
> ...

Can anyone suggest something to try so as to make the connection work?

In addition: VM (192.168.129.128) can reach Gateway (192.168.129.2) as well as host (192.168.129.1). But host (192.168.129.1) cannot reach Gateway (192.168.129.2), ping no response. Strange.

Comment: where your Tomcat is actually running? Is it on host (10.10.31.194) or on the VM 192.168.129.1?

Comment: The Tomcat runs on the local host (10.10.31.194). BTW, 10.10.31.194 and 192.168.129.1 are IP of different interfaces of the same "host". I intend to connect VM (IP 192.168.129.128) to Tomcat via NAT 192.169.129.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have adress=0.0.0.0 in server.xml Connector's tag for port 8080. It will tell Tomcat to listen on all interfaces available on the host.
Restart Tomcat after the change.

Comment: I added the attribute to Connector and not it listens on 192.168.129.1, so the host can access the server via 192.168.129.1. But other machines or the VMs are still not able to connect to 192.168.129.1. I used Wireshark and sniffed an HTTP packet from source 192.168.129.128 to destination 10.87.10.207 when I sent a HTTP GET request in my VM (192.168.129.128) (GET http://192.168.129.1:8080/ HTTP/1.1\r\n). Where does the wired address 10.87.10.207 come from?

Comment: Have you restarted Tomcat?

Comment: Here is one problem with Tomcat restart, sometimes shutdown.sh doesn't kill Java running the server. Try to kill all java instances running Tomcat and then start Tomcat again.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I restarted Tomcat and even Eclipse. The host can access the page now. However the VM still cannot. This time the destination of the HTTP request from the VM goes to 10.12.251.7.

Comment: where this IP (10.12.251.7) is coming from? Do you have any port forwarding settings in your VMNet8 config?

Comment: Yet another thing - if you're running Tomcat from Eclipse, try to do it in a standalone mode to be in full control. I don't know what config Eclipse is using for Tomcat.

Comment: I think I figured out the reason. It was something with the proxy server. Now that I let the VM bypass proxy server with address range 192.168.0.0/16 it can reach the host's Tomcat server. Thanks for help!

Comment: Good luck and don't forget to vote/accept - that 0.0.0.0 thing is a must when you want to listen on all network interfaces. It's quite common for many servers, not only Tomcat.